# Loading an external .NET Standard 2.0 assembly with blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard, webassembly, blazor

In a Blazor app, I want to load an external assembly and execute a method. For this, I have created a new ASP.Net Core webapplication using the Blazor template.

Then, in a Razor Page (which will be compiled and executed by browser/wasm) I use reflection to load the assembly and run the method (based on code [found here](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1025))

```c#
// download external assembly from server
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://localhost:62633/_framework/MyCustomLib.dll");

//load assembly
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes);

// get type/method info
var type = assembly.GetType("MyCustomLib.MyCustomClass");
var method = type.GetMethod("WriteSomething");

// instantiate object and run method
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
method.Invoke(classInstance, null);
```

The method `WriteSomething` contains a single `Console.WriteLine()` which prints something in the browser's console, thanks to blazor/mono.wasm goodness. The complete code in this library is:

```c#
namespace MyCustomLib
{
    public class MyCustomClass
    {
        public void WriteSomething()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("This is printed from a loaded dll 3 !");
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Successful result in chrome's console]

As you can see, this works great when MyCustomLib.dll is built as a **.NET Framework** Class Library. However, I want to use a **.NET Standard** Class Library.

When I build a `MyCustomLib.dll` as a .NET Standard 2.0 library, and execute the same blazor app, I get the following error in the browser's console:

> Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.

I would expect mono.wasm would have loaded the necessary dependencies to support .NET Standard assemblies.

- Loading the assembly into the AppDomain yields the same result.

```c#
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(bytes);
```

- Switching down to netstandard 1.6 gives me a similar error, this time about `System.Runtime` (because mono.wasm expects `Mono.Runtime` I assume).
- Maybe there's a way to perform `LoadAssembly` on the assemblies referenced by the netstandard2.0 package, but I wouldn't know how.

How can I load a .NET Standard 2.0 into the browser environment using Blazor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some further investigation, I've concluded that my problem is that my external library is not properly linked to the mono.net dependencies. This is why, when you build a Blazor app, it is compiled a second time to /dist/_framework/_bin.

I've found three possible solutions to this problem:

### 1. Turn the external class library into a Blazor Web app

This way, your app will automatically be converted to a mono-compatible assembly when built. A simple peek in to a Blazor .csproj shows the dependencies needed to achieve this. For it to work, I had to change the .csproj of my external assembly:

from a default netstandard library:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

into a web app:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <RunCommand>dotnet</RunCommand>
        <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="0.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

These are the only dependencies needed. On build, the compatible assembly will be found in the /dist/_framework/_bin folder. It can then be loaded using the methods described in the question.

This **works**, but feels a bit hacky because the only reason we're turning the library into a web app is so that it can compile itself into a properly linked assembly.

### 2. Load the netstandard2.0 mono facade

Another solution is to unzip the Nuget Package from [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build/) and grab the netstandard.dll. It's found in the `tools\mono\bcl\Facades` folder. Now, when doing the following in the main Blazor app:

```
var netstandard = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://localhost:62633/_framework/netstandard.dll");
var externallib = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://localhost:62633/_framework/MyCustomLib.dll");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(netstandard);
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(externallib);
```

then the *unmodified* netstandard 2.0 library `MyCustomLib` will be loaded without errors.

- No need to change it to a web app
- This **works**, but it feels even hackier than the first solution, unsure whether this will fail later along the way...

### 3. Use the Blazor Build tools

The Blazor Build tools, currently found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Components/Blazor/Build), they have a `ResolveRuntimeDependenciesCommand` command for the CLI which seems to do exactly what a blazor web app is doing when it spits output to /_framework/_bin. 
I'm still looking at how this could be used to convert a "non blazor-webapp" assembly into a mono-compatible one.

Feel free to comment or answer with additional information. I'm leaving this question open until a "cleaner" solution is found.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the blazor linker stripping out the dependency to `netstandard` since it's not explicitly used in the main WebAssemblyHost project.

When dynamically loading a DLL that uses `netstandard`, it will assume that it was already loaded and crash.

If you plan to load assemblies dynamically, I recommend using

```
<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>
```

to ensure non of the base dependencies is stripped out.